# DoIP TCP a pair of port numbers

Tags: tcp

According to ISO_13400_2_June_2012

> TCP uses a pair of port numbers (one sending, called remote port, and
>   one receiving, called local port) to identify a connection. The
>   sending port on one host will be the receiving port on the other and
>   vice versa. The ports listed in Table 6 are the receiving ports on the
>   DoIP entities that shall be used for TCP connections between external
>   test equipment and DoIP entities.

My question is : Does that mean that the Tester **also should use 13400 as port number** or can use any other port

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The passive, listening socket that is accepting connections (the "server" socket) is listening on a specified and well-known port number.

What port number the connecting application (the "client") uses is irrelevant, and for most applications will be assigned automatically by the operating system.